# how to enhance execution speed of large functions inside a custom URL scheme handler

Tags: javascript, ios, html, url

i'm developing an application on iphone that uses html5 and native code. at some part when i am at html level and i want to do some native operations, i call a custom protocol,
for example: test:// ... . on native  part the protocol handler intercepts the call and proceeds. i'm just wondering if for some reason the functions to be executed in native part(after the url was called) were large and took a long time to execute, i'll be stuck at the html part waiting for the handler to finish executing  all functions.
is there any suggestions to overcome this issue?

javascript side:

```
window.location=urlScheme://...
```

ios side:

```
handler(){

// functions to be executed
}
```